# How to backup account information from Geth in a Docker container?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, docker

I created a Geth node using the default [Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ethereum/client-go/), but realized I need to make some adjustments to the `docker run` command, which requires removing the current container. How do I backup my current account information so that isn't lost when removing the container?

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum accounts are saved in the `$HOME/.ethereum/keystore` folder. Since the Docker container is set to run geth as root, that translates to `/root/.ethereum/keystore`

Using the `docker cp` command we can get that file out of a running container:

```
docker cp CONTAINERNAME:/root/.ethereum/keystore keystore
```

Replace `CONTAINERNAME` with the name of your running geth container.

If you wish to keep an account long-term, and save the chain data already synced from your Docker container, set up the `/root/.ethereum/` folder as a data volume for the Docker container when you start it up:

```
docker volume create --name geth-data
docker run -d -v geth-data:/root/.ethereum --name geth ethereum/client-go
```

That will create a volume named `geth-data` that will persist even if the `ethereum/client-go` container is destroyed. To get data out of that volume you can spin up a simple container and then copy the data out:

```
docker run -v geth-data:/data --name geth-backup ubuntu:wily
docker cp geth-backup:/data ethereum-data
```

With that `docker cp` command you can copy the contents out where you want. Or, the one-liner:

```
docker run --rm -v geth-data:/data -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:wily tar cvf /backup/ethereum-data.tar /data
```

That will place an `ethereum-data.tar` archive in the folder you run it on. The `ubuntu:wily` container is used as a simple container because that's the base container used by the `ethereum/client-go` container, so if you've been running `ethereum/client-go` containers, you already have that one downloaded.